# Django - Object of type '__proxy__' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

When I want to import variants in a CSV file format it can't accept them in JSON format.
Here is the code:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def CSVBulkUpdate(request, model, pk=None):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    mapped_obj_to_import = []
    data = request.data["data"]
    mapped_obj = request.data["mapped_obj"]
    print(data)
    for row in data:
        row_obj = {}
        if row.get("id") or row.get("name"):
            for key, item in mapped_obj.items():
                if item and row.get(key) != "":
                    row_obj[item] = covertObjects(item, row.get(key))
            mapped_obj_to_import.append(row_obj)

    try:
        if model == "product":
            csvBulkUpdate(user.id, mapped_obj_to_import)
        else:
            csvVariantBulkUpdate(user.id, mapped_obj_to_import)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", str(e))
        return Response({"data": str(e)}, status=400)

    return Response({"data": "success"}, status=200)
```

The csvVariantBulkUpdatefunction code:

```
def csvVariantBulkUpdate(user, dataToUpdate):
    serializer_class = serializers.VariantImportUpdateSerializer
    model = models.Variant
    serializer_unapproved_class = serializers.UnapprovedVariantImportSerializer
    module = "variant"
    view = "Variant"

    list_data = dataToUpdate

    user = User.objects.get(id=user)
    print(user)
    variants = []
    relational_fields = ["size", "color"]

    results = {"success": {}, "failure": {}}
    for i, item in enumerate(list_data):
        results["failure"][item["id"]] = {}
        try:
            record = model.objects.get(id=item["id"])
            item["product"] = record.product.id
            if user.is_admin:
                print("variant update admin view triggered")
                update_size_in_approved = False
                update_color_in_approved = False

                if "size" in item:
                    error, data = sizesValidate(item["size"])
                    if error:
                        results["failure"][item["id"]]["size"] = data
                    item["size"] = data
                    update_size_in_approved = True

                if "color" in item:
                    error, data = colorValidate(item["color"])
                    if error:
                        results["failure"][item["id"]]["color"] = data
                    item["color"] = data
                    update_color_in_approved = True

                if len(results["failure"][item["id"]]) == 0:
                    serializer = serializer_class(record, data=item)
                    if serializer.is_valid():
                        for (key, value) in item.items():
                            if key not in ["id", "product"]:
                                if (
                                    key in relational_fields
                                    and update_size_in_approved
                                    and update_color_in_approved
                                ):
                                    if update_size_in_approved:
                                        value = get_size_instance(value)
                                    elif update_color_in_approved:
                                        value = get_color_instance(value)
                                    data = {
                                        "field": key,
                                        "variant": record,
                                        "approved": True,
                                        key: value,
                                    }
                                else:
                                    data = {
                                        "field": key,
                                        "variant": record,
                                        "approved": True,
                                        key: value,
                                    }
                                try:
                                    models.ApprovedVariant.objects.get(
                                        variant_id=item.get("id"),
                                        field=key,
                                    )
                                    models.ApprovedVariant.objects.filter(
                                        variant_id=item.get("id"),
                                        field=key,
                                    ).update(**data)
                                except models.ApprovedVariant.DoesNotExist:
                                    models.ApprovedVariant.objects.create(**data)

                        serializer.save()

                        # Activity logging
                        content = "%s updated a %s with ID %s" % (
                            user.name,
                            module,
                            item["id"],
                        )
                        create_activity(user, "Update", module, record.id, content)

                        variants.append(record.id)
                        results["success"][
                            item["id"]
                        ] = "Variant has been updated successfully."
                    else:
                        print("errors:: ", serializer.errors)
                        results["failure"][item["id"]] = serializer.errors
            else:
                item[module] = record.id
                product = serializers.VariantSerializer(record)
                data = product.data
                data["size"] = record.size
                data["color"] = record.color
                data[module] = record

                if "hidden" in data:
                    del data["hidden"]
                if "id" in data:
                    del data["id"]

                update_size_in_approved = False
                update_color_in_approved = False

                if "size" in item:
                    error, data = sizesValidate(item["size"])
                    if error:
                        results["failure"][item["id"]]["size"] = data
                    item["size"] = data
                    update_size_in_approved = True

                if "color" in item:
                    error, data = colorValidate(item["color"])
                    if error:
                        results["failure"][item["id"]]["color"] = data
                    item["color"] = data
                    update_color_in_approved = True

                if len(results["failure"][item["id"]]) == 0:
                    data_unapproved = models.UnapprovedVariant.objects.create(**data)

                    serializer = serializer_unapproved_class(data_unapproved, data=item)
                    if serializer.is_valid():
                        serializer.validated_data["unapproved"] = True
                        for (key, value) in item.items():
                            if (
                                key in relational_fields
                                and update_size_in_approved
                                and update_color_in_approved
                            ):
                                if update_size_in_approved:
                                    value = get_size_instance(value)
                                elif update_color_in_approved:
                                    value = get_color_instance(value)
                                data3 = {
                                    "field": key,
                                    "variant": record,
                                    "approved": True,
                                    key: value,
                                }
                            else:
                                data3 = {
                                    "field": key,
                                    "variant": record,
                                    "approved": True,
                                    key: value,
                                }

                            try:
                                models.ApprovedVariant.objects.get(
                                    variant_id=item.get("id"),
                                    field=key,
                                )
                                models.ApprovedVariant.objects.filter(
                                    variant_id=item.get("id"),
                                    field=key,
                                ).update(**data)
                            except models.ApprovedVariant.DoesNotExist:
                                models.ApprovedVariant.objects.create(**data3)

                        result = serializer.save().id
                        message = (
                            "%s updated a %s with ID %s \n approve to show in the list."
                            % (user.name, module, record.id)
                        )

                        admins = User.objects.filter(is_admin=True)
                        for admin in admins:
                            notification = Notifications(
                                sent_by=user,
                                user=admin,
                                message=message,
                                content_id=record.id,
                                module=view,
                                action="Update",
                                unapproved_id=result,
                            )
                            notification.save()

                        # Activity logging
                        content = "%s updated a %s with ID %s" % (
                            user.name,
                            module,
                            record.id,
                        )
                        create_activity(user, "Update", module, record.id, content)

                        variants.append(record.id)
                        results["success"][
                            item["id"]
                        ] = "Variant update request has been added successfully for approval."
                    else:
                        results["failure"][item["id"]] = serializer.errors
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occured: ", str(e))
            results["failure"][item["id"]] = str(e)

    has_error = 0

    if len(results["failure"]):
        results["import_success"] = False
        has_error = 1

    # save update progress
    models.UpdateProgress.objects.create(
        user=user,
        productsCount=len(variants),
        response=results,
        has_error=has_error,
        is_read=False,
    )
    import_variant_response(user.id, results, "Update")
    return results
```

I applied yaml but didn't work. I also use force_text to an objects but didn't resolve my problem.
When importing the file "Bad Request: /api/v1/variant/bulk/import_update/" and "Object of type '**proxy**' is not JSON serializable" this error shows in terminal.

Comment: Please see how to make a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the following line in the function:

```
data = request.data["data"]
```

request.data is not in the expected format, or it doesn't contain the expected data.
Can you update your question about the format of the request.data object that you're sending to this endpoint?

Comment: That line of code isn't doing any JSON serializing.